# How to get rid of the pointer from integer without a cast error?

Tags: c, inotify

I have made `inotifyFunc` to monitor two paths. Nothing is giving me an error except the last line *[the code that I have taken from the main function]* that is `monitor.wd[0]`. The error is

> warning: passing argument 3 of ‘inotifyFunc’ makes pointer from
> integer without a cast

I don't know what is the problem? Although the above line `monitor.wd[0] = *pathname1;` didn't give me an error.

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path, uint32_t *maskPtr, int *wd[2]){
    monitor.fd = inotify_init();
    if(fcntl(monitor.fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)){
       perror("inotify not initialized: ");
       exit(0);
    }

    *wd[0] = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, *maskPtr);
    *wd[1] = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, *maskPtr);

    if(*wd[0] < 0 || *wd[1] < 0){
        perror("Sorry");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

**Code taken from the main function**

```
monitor.mask[0] = ENOENT;
monitor.mask[1] = IN_CREATE;

printf("Choose the source path: ");
scanf("%s", pathname1);
monitor.wd[0] = *pathname1;
inotifyFunc(pathname1, &monitor.mask[0], monitor.wd[0]);
```

Comment: It might be just plain ignorance from me (I've never used inotify), but if `monitor` is of type `struct inotify_event`, as I suspect, `wd` is of type `int` and absolutely not an array of strings. Also, the `mask` field of the same struct is of type `uint32_t`, so I don't see why you used it as an array. Could you please post the struct definition of the type of `monitor`?

Comment: I think you chose a bad name `wd`. What does this name mean? Which more descriptive name could you use? Maybe, if you answer this question, you can fix your problem. Or, if not, you can at least clarify your original question.

Comment: *Never* use `"%s"` in scanf.  It is no better than `gets`.  If you're going to use scanf for this, at the very least use a width in the conversion specifier.  eg `char path[256]; scanf("%255s", path);`

Answer (score 1):

From this scanf here

```
scanf("%s", pathname1);
```

It seems that `pathname1` is a pointer to `char`. If that's the case, then to do that

```
monitor.wd[0] = *pathname1;
```

`monitor.wd[0]` has to be a `char`. So when you pass it to a function you should receive a simple `char` rather than an array of pointers to `int`: `int *wd[2]`

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path, uint32_t *maskPtr, char wd)
```

If you give more context maybe we can get what you were trying to do.

Comment: okay but if I declared `char wd` then my array will be useless. I wrote char wd[2] but this line `inotifyFunc(pathname1, &monitor.mask[0], monitor.wd[0]);` is still giving me the same error.

Comment: For now it seems that `monitor.wd[0]` is just a character. You can't pass a character and expect to receive an array of 2 characters

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> monitor.wd[0] = *pathname1;
> ```

This line makes no sense. I have no idea what you were trying to do, but whatever it is, this line is definitely wrong. `inotifyFunc` only uses `monitor.wd` for output, so there's no point in setting `monitor.wd` to some value before calling `inotifyFunc`. Furthermore `monitor.wd[0]` is a pointer to an integer (although maybe you intended an integer), and assigning a character to that makes no sense. And why would you take the first character of a file path anyway? So remove this line.

Given the error you're getting, it seems that `monitor.wd` is an array of integers:

```
struct {
    …
    int wd[2];
} monitor;
```

(But I shouldn't have to guess! **Always post complete code when you ask a question.**) If so, you're declaring and using it wrong in `inotifyFunc`: `wd` in `inotifyFunc` is an array of pointers to integers, not an array of integers. Assuming that `monitor.wd` is in fact an array of integers as declared above, change `inotifyFunc` to use it correctly by removing the spurious pointer dereferences:

```
void inotifyFunc(char *path, uint32_t *maskPtr, int wd[2]){
    monitor.fd = inotify_init();
    if(fcntl(monitor.fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)){
       perror("inotify not initialized: ");
       exit(0);
    }

    wd[0] = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, *maskPtr);
    wd[1] = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, path, *maskPtr);

    if(wd[0] < 0 || wd[1] < 0){
        perror("Sorry");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to have an array of pointers to integers in `inotifyFunc`, then fix the declaration of `monitor.wd` and make sure that the pointers point to allocated memory before calling it.